# docker compose up gving error as I need to stop mysql service ERROR: for demo_db_1 Cannot start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have spring boot app with below Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo.jar"]
```

I can able to build docker image successfully

and this below is my docker-compose

```
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

version: '3.7'

# Define services
services:
  # App backend service
  app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
    build:
      context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the `polling-app-server` directory.
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: empserver
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - db # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_entries?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root     

  # Database Service (Mysql)
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_entries
      MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
```

Now I did

docker-compose up

```
Starting demo_db_1 ... error                                                                                                                                                
ERROR: for demo_db_1  Cannot start service db: failed to create endpoint demo_db_1 on network demo_default: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: failed to create endpoint demo_db_1 on network demo_default: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Now as per one SO solution they said they need to stop services so I stop mysql service.

Then it run the docker-compose up successfully.

but it is not able to send data into mysql from my spring app

it gave below error as service stopped

```
 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
empserver     |         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         ... 56 common frames omitted
empserver     | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
empserver     |         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
empserver     |         ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: seems like DB container is not ready to accept the connection and your application tried to connect, can you verify this using command like `mysql -u localhost -u root -proot`

Comment: yes I can open my db and its table employees

Comment: so seems like the application trying to connect before its ready to accept the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that application is booting up before the database server is available. You need to wait for db to be available and then start the application server. There is a utility available to just do this kind of synchronization.
[https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait]

Modify your dockerfile to include this script in it

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} demo.jar
## Add the wait script to the image
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo.jar"]
```

and with this you will have the wait script now part of your image and can be used as shown below:
Please pay attention to command and environment vars added to app-server section. I am currently using this exact set up where i have 4 services and 2 database running in docker compose and all services need to wait for both db to be available and 2 of the 4 services need to wait for another service to be available.

```
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

version: '3.7'

# Define services
services:
  # App backend service
  app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
    build:
      context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the `polling-app-server` directory.
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "/wait && java -jar /demo.jar"
    container_name: empserver
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - db # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee_entries?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root     
      WAIT_HOSTS: db:3306
  # Database Service (Mysql)
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_entries
      MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
network:
  my-network:
```